# Projeto independente Injeção de Dependencias Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá! Estou utilizando a arquitetura do tipo DDD para fazer um projeto, nele tenho a camada de CrossCutting, e nessa camada pensei em adicionar um projeto class library com Ninject para que não fique na parte da apresentação.

Realizei algumas tentativas mas não encontrei nada que resolvesse o problema... vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Isso foi o mais próximo que cheguei:

```
public class CrossCuttingModule : NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind(typeof(IAppService<>)).To(typeof(AppService<>));
        Bind<IClienteService>().To<ClienteService>();
        Bind<IProdutoService>().To<ProdutoService>();

        Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
        Bind<IProdutoRepository>().To<ProdutoRepository>();
        Bind<IClienteRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou estudando DDD e também fiz um projeto recente seguindo o exemplo do [Eduardo Pires](http://eduardopires.net.br) que pode ser encontrado nesse [LINK](http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/), no projeto teste ao instalar o `Ninject` pelo `nugget` o mesmo cria uma classe na pasta `App_Start` do projeto chamada `NinjectWebCommon`, nesta classe há um método `static void` chamado `RegisterServices` onde você registra seus módulos, como exemplo abaixo:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            Bind(typeof(IAppService<>)).To(typeof(AppService<>));
            Bind<IClienteService>().To<ClienteService>();
            Bind<IProdutoService>().To<ProdutoService>();

            Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
            Bind<IProdutoRepository>().To<ProdutoRepository>();
            Bind<IClienteRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>();
        }
```

Comment: Sim, mas nesse caso fica no projeto MVC né ? Eu gostaria em um projeto separado...

Answer (score 0):

Em seu projeto `CrossCutting` você utiliza o [CommonServiceLocator](https://github.com/unitycontainer/commonservicelocator).

Um projeto que utilizo par isso é o [NinjectAdapter.Unofficial](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.Unofficial/)(como o nome já diz, não é oficial, porém sempre atendeu minhas necessidades). O comando de instalação no Nuget é:

> install-Package CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.Unofficial

E neste mesmo projeto, você cria uma `Classe Container`, onde você indica sua classe `CrossCuttingModule` no `StandardKernel`, assim ele irá conter um  `método` para selecionar seu módulo criado, ficando assim esta classe:

```
 public class Container
    {
        public Container()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(GetModule()));
        }

        public StandardKernel GetModule()
        {
            //Chama a sua classe CrossCuttingModule
            return new StandardKernel(new CrossCuttingModule());
        }
    }
```

Feito isso em seu projeto `Class Library`, basta você referenciar no `RegisterServices` em seu `NinjectWebCommon` em seu projeto MVC, ficando assim:

```
/// <summary>
        ///     Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        private static StandardKernel RegisterServices()
        {
            return new Container().GetModule();
        }
```

Feito isso, basta fazer os `Bind<>` em seu projeto em sua classe `CrossCuttingModule` normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema, na camada de CrossCutting instalei o Ninject, e realizei os bind's classe concreta/interfaces, na camada da View (MVC/WebAPI) também instalei o Ninject, e no container chamei a minha classe da camada de crosscutting passando como parâmetro o meu container da classe web.